# Equivalence of knots: ambient isotopy vs. homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

I am looking into knot theory and have found two different definitions stating that two knots $K_1$ and $K_2$ are equivalent, namely the concept of an ambient isotopy:

These two knots are ambient isotopic if there is an isotopy $h:\mathbb{R}^3 \times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $h(K_1,0)=K_1$ and $h(K_1,1)=K_2$.

Or the other definition takes a homeomorphism $g:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that maps $K_1$ to $K_2$ (ie. $h(K_1) = K_2$).

I guess these definitions are not identical and I suppose this has something to do with orientations of your knots. However I find it a bit hard to get my head around it. So I hoped someone could either prove I'm right by giving a counterexample or prove I'm wrong (ie. prove these concept are identical)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'll be working in $S^3$ for this answer, as it is generally the more convenient place to do knot theory. It does not cause problems: just extend your homeomorphisms to be homeomorphisms of $S^3$, for instance.

These are not identical, but they almost are. In particular, the reverse of a knot need not be isotopic to it, but you can just reflect along a hyperplane to get a homeomorphism.

But if you replace "homeomorphism" with "orientation-preserving homeomorphism", they *are* equivalent. This is because every orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $S^3$ is isotopic to the identity! This follows from a combination of [Alexander's trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick) and the [isotopy extension theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotopy_%28in_topology%29). If you want to do knot theory in the smooth category, working with smooth isotopies instead of continuous isotopies, you need to know that every orientation-preserving diffeomorphism is isotopic to the identity; I think Cerf was the first to prove this.

There is one other common definition of equivalence for knots: isotopy of embeddings.

A knot is an embedding $S^1 \to S^3$. An *isotopy* between two embeddings $f_0, f_1$ is a map $f_t: S^1 \times [0,1] \to S^3$ such that each $f_t$ is an embedding. This turns out to not be the correct notion of equivalence for knots - it would force all tame knots to be equivalent! What one does to fix this is either demand that the isotopy be smooth, or that it be locally flat. (See [this page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotopy_%28in_topology%29) again for details on being locally flat.)

Now this is precisely the hypothesis we need to use the isotopy extension theorem: so any (locally flat/smooth) isotopy of embeddings automatically lifts to an ambient isotopy, giving us something equivalent to the standard definition.

EDIT: I was having some trouble reconstructing the argument I suggested above to show that $\pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(S^3)$ is trivial. So I'll write an argument here. Actually I'll show that $\pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(S^n) = 0$ for all $n$.

This is trivial for $n=0$. Inductively assume it's trivial for $n-1$. Pick an orientation-preserving homeomorphism $f$; $f(S^{n-1})$ bounds a ball on both sides. Isotope $f$ so that $f(S^{n-1})$ does not include the poles. Pick a standard 'longitude sphere' $S^{n-1}$s (the level sets of the height function of $S^n \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$) that lie inside one of the balls that $f(S^{n-1})$ bounds (this is possible by compactness of $S^{n-1}$ and continuity of the height function). By the [annulus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem) there is a locally flat isotopy of embeddings from $f(S^{n-1})$ to this longitude sphere; then there is an isotopy from this longitude sphere to the equator $S^{n-1}$. Using the isotopy extension theorem $f$ then is isotopic to an orientation-preserving homeomorphism that preserves the equator; we can also assume that it sends the north hemisphere to the north hemisphere. This new $f'$ restricts to an orientation-preserving map on $S^{n-1}$; this restriction is isotopic to the identity; use isotopy extension. So $f'$ is isotopic to $f''$ that preserves $S^{n-1}$ pointwise. $f''$ is the union of two homeomorphisms of $D^n$ (the northern and southern hemispheres), identity on the boundary, along their boundary; the Alexander trick shows that these are isotopic to the identity. So we have produced an isotopy of $f$ to the identity as desired.

In the case we care about - $n=3$ - the only hard result we used is the annulus theorem in dimension 3, which is reasonably elementary.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was incredibly helpful.

Comment: Is every orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $S^n$ isotopic to the identity for $n\ne3$?

Comment: @Akiva At the very least I claim so in this answer - that's the $\pi_0$ statement.

Answer (score 6):

Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* (page 34) has a very elementary proof: [image]

Filling in the blanks:

1. *We may assume that $f(0) = 0$*: Translation is an isotopy.
2. *We write $f$ in the form $f(x) = x_1g_1(x) + \cdots + x_mg_m(x)$*: [Hadamard's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma).
3. *...the linear mapping $df_0$, which is clearly isotopic to the identity*: $GL^+(m)$ is connected.

In symbols, the lemma says $\operatorname{Diff}^+(\mathbf R^m) \subseteq \operatorname{Diff}_0(\mathbf R^m)$. But it's easy to see that the reverse inclusion also holds. Thus, the main result here is $\operatorname{Diff}^+(\mathbf R^m) = \operatorname{Diff}_0(\mathbf R^m)$.