# Isotopy between homeomorphisms of open balls

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. A *homotopy* from a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ to a continuous function $g: X \to Y$ is a continuous function $H : X \times [0, 1] \to Y$ such that $H(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $H(x, 1) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. An *isotopy* is a homotopy such that $H(\cdot, t)$ is an embedding for every $t \in [0, 1]$; isotopy requires $f$ and $g$ to be embeddings.

Suppose $X = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 < 1\}$ is the open $n$-ball, and let $f, g : X \to Y$ be homeomorphisms. Does there always exist an isotopy from $f$ to $g$?

[Alexander's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick) solves a similar problem, but on closed $n$-balls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it is not as elementary as the Alexander trick. Your group is the same as the space of homeomorphisms of $\Bbb R^n$, and you want to know that the subspace of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms is connected. The case $n=1$ is easy to prove by hand, so we will suppose $n>1$.

In fact, $\text{Homeo}(\Bbb R^n) \cong \text{Homeo}(S^n, \text{pt})$, the space of homeomorphisms of the sphere that fix a point. This sits into a fibration $$\text{Homeo}(S^n, \text{pt}) \to \text{Homeo}(S^n) \to S^n,$$ and similarly for the orientation-preserving versions (which I denote $\text{Homeo}^+$).

So if $\text{Homeo}^+(S^n)$ is connected, we see from the long exact sequence $$\cdots \to \pi_1 S^n \to \pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(S^n, \text{pt}) \to \pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(S^n) \to \pi_0 S^n$$ that $\pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(\Bbb R^n)$ is connected.

What remains is an inductive argument using the [annulus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem) to show that this group is connected; I have written a proof out in the second half of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1312016/98602). The idea is to first demand your homeomorphism sends the equator to itself, inductively isotope that to the identity, and then use the Alexander trick on the two hemispheres.

Comment: How do you define an orientation-preserving homeomorphism?

Comment: [You define orientations homologically.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Homology_and_the_orientability_of_general_manifolds)

Comment: The link uses the notation $H_n(M, M \setminus \{p\}; \mathbf{Z})$. It looks like a relative singular homology group, but what is the meaning of $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: @kaba the integers.

Comment: What I mean is that I have not seen a three-argument form of a homology group before. What is the role of the third argument?

Comment: Perhaps the third argument is a ring (?) for the coefficients of the singular simplices, which usually is the integers, but can be generalized?

Comment: Yes, this is correct (but you only need an abelian group). I don't really know sources that don't simultaneously introduce homology with arbitrary coefficients. Certainly this is what Hatcher does.

Comment: If this is confusing you, there is almost no harm in dropping the + and modifying the inductive argument to see that $\pi_0 \text{Homeo}(\Bbb R^n) = \Bbb Z/2$ more directly. The only difficulty is showing that reflection on a hyperplane is not isotopic to the identity. This requires the notion of orientation.

Comment: What I think I understood up to this point: 1) the homeomorphism $\text{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^n) \approx \text{Homeo}(S^n, pt)$ follows from one-point compactification. 2) The fibration is a Serre fibration. 3) The long exact sequence holds for Serre fibrations in general. 4) There is a typo in "$\pi_0 \text{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is connected."; $\pi_0$ should be removed. 5) "show that this group is connected" refers to $\text{Homeo}^+(S^n)$. Therefore, what is left is to understand the annulus theorem.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. (I won't edit to avoid bumping). I do not suggest trying to understand the annulus theorem. It is exceedingly difficult topology in dimensions greater than two, and in dimension 2 is similar to the Schoenflies theorem. This is one of those things that is better left as a black box unless you are trying to extend it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is left is to understand your proof which uses the annulus theorem. I'll dive into that next.

Comment: Everything seems to check out! The final thing that remains unclear to me is orientation. What I think has been shown is that if I have two orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of $X$, then they are in the same connected component. However, if one of the homeomorphisms is not orientation-preserving, then they are in different components, and there is no isotopy, right?

Comment: @kaba Correct. I do not see an elementary (non-homological) argument for this, but it's frankly surprising we got this far at all while never mentioning homology. :)