# Ambient isotopic is equivalent to orientation-preserving homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, curves, knot-theory, piecewise-continuity

I'm currently studying Knot Theory from Gerhard Burde - Heiner Zieschang "[Knots](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/burdzies.pdf)". I'm stuck with the proof of $(1) \Rightarrow 2$ the following:

[image]

The question was asked previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311865/equivalence-of-knots-ambient-isotopy-vs-homeomorphism) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185272/reference-for-a-fact-on-homeomorphic-knot-complements), but the theorems used aren't within my reach, I'm trying to find a proof as elementary as possible.

The first question is the definition of *simplex star*, not given previously in the book.
The troubles comes with the omitted details left in the following sentence:

> Next, we choose a point $P_1 \ne P_0$ in the simplex star of $P_0$,
> and by similar arguments we construct an ambienty isotopy $H^1$ with
> $h_1^1 \circ h_1^0 \circ f$ leaving fixed the $1-$simple $[P_0,P_1]$.

Any help, details or alternative proof of the above proposition would be appreciated. I also left a picture of Figure $1.5$.

[image]